# What is wrong with this C++ Code?

Tags: c++

i am a beginner and i have a problem :

this code doesnt compile :

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "readdir.h"
#include "mysql.h"
#include "readimage.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc>1){
    readdir(argv[1]);
  //  test();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    std::cout << "Bitte Pfad angeben !" << std::endl ;
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

readimage.cpp

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace Magick; using namespace std;

void readImage(std::vector<string> &filenames) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < filenames.size(); ++i) {
        try {
            Image img("binary/" + filenames.at(i));

            for (unsigned int y = 1; y < img.rows(); y++) {
                for (unsigned int x = 1; x < img.columns(); x++) {
                    ColorRGB rgb(img.pixelColor(x, y));
                    // cout << "x: " << x << "   y: " << y << " : "  << rgb.red() << endl;
                }
            }
            cout << "done " << i << endl;
        } catch (Magick::Exception & error) {
            cerr << "Caught Magick++ exception: " << error.what() << endl;
        }
    } }
```

readimage.h

```
#ifndef _READIMAGE_H
#define _READIMAGE_H

#include <Magick++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace Magick;
using namespace std;

void readImage(vector<string> &filenames)


#endif  /* _READIMAGE_H */
```

If want to compile it with this code :

> g++ main.cpp `Magick++-config --cflags
>   --cppflags --ldflags --libs` readimage.cpp

i get this error message :

> main.cpp:5: error: expected
>   initializer before ‘int’

i have no clue , why ? :(

Can somebody help me ? :)

Comment: Unrelated: **Never ever have `using namespace` in your header files**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In *readimage.h*, you are missing a semicolon after your `readImage` function declaration.

Comment: awww man... how come , the error is in the main ?! :D

Comment: @mr.bio: In fact, the error is just after an #include; this suggests that the error is at the end of the file you are including. And I confess this has happened to me quite a few times.

Comment: Because *readimage.h* is the last file to be included into *main.cpp*. `#include ...` is a straight text substitution. An error in an `#include` -ed file affects the compilation of the file that `#include` -ed it...

Comment: The error is in main, because #include actually works as text-pasting. So when the compiler builds main.cpp it sees all the code from your includes as one big chunk of code, not separate files. Since the last line in readimage.h is incomplete on its own, it then proceeds to look into main.cpp (whitespace doesn't bother the compiler. So the line ends up looking like "void readImage(vector<string> &filenames) int main(int argc, char** argv) {" which wouldn't compile. It's just split between the two files so it's hard to see.

Comment: Tnaks.. now i got the point :)

Answer (score 5):

One of the first things you should do when compiling for the first time is to try one piece of code at a time. Don't throw a bunch of code together and hope that it compiles. Instead, take it one fragment at a time.  So here, you might comment out your includes and the code that you expect to use the stuff in those files.

At first glance, it looks like

```
void readImage(vector<string> &filenames)
```

is missing a semicolon at the end of the line, since you're declaring it.

Answer (score 3):

In readImage.h, you're missing a semicolon after the readImage function prototype.

Answer (score 3):

This function declaration:

```
void readImage(vector<string> &filenames)
```

is missing a semicolon at the end. An unrelated issue - your include guard names:

```
#ifndef _READIMAGE_H
```

are illegal. Names that begin with an underscore and an uppercase letter are reserved in C++ - you are not allowed to create such names yourself.

And in your loop:

```
for (unsigned int y = 1; y < img.rows(); y++) {
```

are you sure you should be beginning the loop at 1 and not at zero?

Comment: the includeguards are autogenerated by Netbeans

Comment: @mr.bio Really? Then netbeans is broken. But I suspect that it is just some textual template that needs fixing,

Comment: Thanks .. for the Loop advice .. fixed ;)

Answer (score 1):

`;` is missing at the end of `readimage.h`

Since, `main.cpp` is pre-processed first, it finds the error at the last line of `readimage.h` and shows that error occurred before `int` in `main.cpp`

`main.cpp:5: error: expected initializer before ‘int’`

Answer (score 1):

You just need a semicolon at the end of `readImage` declaration in readimage.h:

```
void readImage(vector<string> &filenames);
```